# Distributing VirtualBox image with unlicensed Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, license

In my university research project, we use a VirtualBox image of Windows 7 for demos. Since the software is fairly complex to install, people have asked for a copy of our demo VM image. So far we have said no, because we can't provide the license. But would it be legal for us to distribute an instance of the VM that has never been licensed--i.e., no Windows 7 license key has ever been entered? Or is that considered piracy?

I've seen similar discussions online, but everything I've found involves a retailer or corporate administrator who intends to provide the license in some way. Our intention is to provide the VM image an leave the license question up to the user. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not piracy to distribute an unlicensed copy of the software.

If they will need to license it though they need to match the license rather precisely, and this could make the whole proposal unworkable. For example, they need a license that:

a) matches the language of your Windows 7

b) is 32 or 64 bit appropriately

c) matches your Windows OEM / VLA / Retail status

d) matches the edition of Windows (Home / Pro / Enterprise)

So there are literally dozens of different types of Windows 7 keys, before you even consider non English versions.

To make it more difficult, Windows 7 is now obsolete and getting a key from Microsoft is difficult.

It would be a lot easier to:

a) Rework things to run on Linux, or

b) Distribute a Windows 10 based VM. You can register as a Microsoft OEM and get OEM licenses for Windows 10 really easily, and it probably runs faster than Windows 7

The command you would use to strip a license (there will be lots of fiddly flags to pass to get what you want, there are whole books!) is called sysprep.

Sysprep prepares a machine for distribution.

Really though, Windows 7 is getting creaky, even if we all like it.